# error: expected ‘}’ at end of input -- when there is one

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am getting this error when compiling:

project6.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:

project6.cpp:187: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input

However, there is clearly an end bracket to my int main () function at that line, so I am confused as to why I am getting this error. I also checked all of my other brackets and found none that were not closed. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void initRace(char grid[52][72])
{  
   for(int r = 0; r < 52; r = r + 1)
   {  for(int c = 0; c < 72; c = c + 1)
      {  grid[r][0] = 'X';
         grid[0][c] = 'X';
         grid[r][71] = 'X'; // border
         grid[51][c] = 'X';
      }
      for(int c = 65; c <= 70; c = c + 1)
      {  grid[51][c] = 'F';         // finish line
      }
   }
   for(int r = 1; r <= 35; r = r + 1)
   {  for(int c = 10; c <= 29; c = c + 1)
      {  grid[r][c] = 'X';             // first barrier
      }
   }

   for(int r = 16; r <= 50; r = r + 1)
   {   for(int c = 40; c <=64; c = c + 1)
       {  grid[r][c] = 'X';             //second barrier
       }
   }

   for(int r = 1; r <= 50; r = r + 1)
   {   for(int c =1; c <=9; c = c + 1)
       {  grid[r][c] = ' ';             //first block of spaces
       }
   }

   for(int r = 36; r <= 50; r = r + 1)
   {   for(int c =10; c <=29; c = c + 1)
       {  grid[r][c] = ' ';             //second block of spaces
       }
   }

   for(int r = 1; r <= 50; r = r + 1)
   {   for(int c =30; c <=39; c = c + 1)
       {  grid[r][c] = ' ';             //third block of spaces
       }
   }

   for(int r = 1; r <= 15; r = r + 1)
   {   for(int c =40; c <=64; c = c + 1)
       {  grid[r][c] = ' ';             //fourth block of spaces
       }
   }

   for(int r = 1; r <= 50; r = r + 1)
   {   for(int c =65; c <=70; c = c + 1)
       {  grid[r][c] = ' ';             //fifth block of spaces
       }
   }
   grid[1][1] = 'O';
}

void printRace(char grid[52][72])
{  for (int i = 0 ; i < 52; i = i + 1)
   {  for (int j = 0 ; j < 72; j = j + 1)
      {  cout << grid[i][j] << " ";
      }
      cout << endl;
   }

}

int main(void)
{  char grid[52][72];

   initRace(grid);


   int xAcceleration;
   int yAcceleration;
   int xVelocity = 0;
   int yVelocity = 0;
   int xPosition = 1;
   int yPosition = 1;


   for(int i = 1; i < 100; i = i + 1)
   {  printRace(grid);
      cout << "Horizontal and vertical acceleration (-1,0,1): ";
      cin >> xAcceleration;
      cin >> yAcceleration; 

      if((xAcceleration != 0) && (xAcceleration != 1) && (xAcceleration != -1))
      {  if(i == 1)
         {  cout << "Crashed after " << i << " second" << endl;
         }
         else
         {  cout << "Crashed after " << i << " seconds" << endl;
         printRace(grid);
         i = 500;
      }

      if((yAcceleration != 0) && (yAcceleration != 1) && (yAcceleration != -1))
      {  printRace(grid);
         if(i == 1)
         {  cout << "Crashed after " << i << " second" << endl;
         }
         else
         {  cout << "Crashed after " << i << " seconds" << endl;
         }
         i = 500;
      }

      xVelocity = xVelocity + xAcceleration;
      yVelocity = yVelocity + yAcceleration;

      xPosition = xPosition + xVelocity;
      yPosition = yPosition + yVelocity;


      if((xPosition >= 10) && (xPosition <=29) && (yPosition >= 1) && (yPosition<= 35))
      {  grid[yPosition][xPosition] = 'O';
         printRace(grid);
         cout << "Crashed after " << i << " seconds" << endl;        // crashed into first barrier
         i = 500;
      }

      if((xPosition >= 40) && (xPosition <= 64) && (yPosition >= 16) && (yPosition <= 50))
      {  grid[yPosition][xPosition] = 'O';
         printRace(grid);
         cout << "Crashed after " << i << " seconds" << endl;        // crashed into second barrier
         i = 500;
      }

      if(xPosition <= 0)            //crashed into left border
      {  grid[yPosition][0] = 'O';
         printRace(grid);
         cout << "Crashed after " << i << " seconds" << endl;      
         i = 500;                               
      }

      if(yPosition <= 0)            //crashed into top border
      {  grid[0][xPosition] = 'O';
         printRace(grid);
         cout << "Crashed after " << i << " seconds" << endl;      
         i = 500; 
      }

      if(xPosition >= 71)           //crashed into right border
      {  grid[yPosition][71] = 'O';
         printRace(grid);
         cout << "Crashed after " << i << " seconds" << endl;      
         i = 500; 
      }

      if((yPosition >= 51) && (xPosition >= 1) && (xPosition <= 39))     //crashed into bottom border
      {  grid[51][xPosition] = 'O';
         printRace(grid);
         cout << "Crashed after " << i << " seconds" << endl;      
         i = 500; 
      }

      if((xPosition >= 65) && (xPosition <= 70) && (yPosition >= 51))      // crossed finish line
      {  grid[51][xPosition] = 'O';
         printRace(grid);
         cout << "Finished after " << i << " seconds" << endl;
         i = 500;
      }


      grid[yPosition][xPosition] = 'O';


   }

   return 0;

}      // THIS IS LINE 187
```

Comment: Please work on reducing the program to the smallest one that demonstrates the problem. For example, delete "if" clauses and see if that helps.

Comment: What is wrong with my formatting?

Comment: @user1757575 Horstmann style is only useful when print the code on paper to save vertical space. The most significant problem with this formatting is to make code hard to refactor, as you have to treat first line differently when move it to somewhere else.

Answer (score 4):

One of your else blocks does not have a closing brace... Look below:

```
     else
     {  cout << "Crashed after " << i << " seconds" << endl;
     printRace(grid);
     i = 500;
```

Due to this, the total number of closing braces is not equal to the opening braces, hence the error.

Answer (score 3):

The first `else` statement in the big for-loop misses a closing brace.

Answer (score 1):

The error is here:

```
if((xAcceleration != 0) && (xAcceleration != 1) && (xAcceleration != -1))
 {  if(i == 1)
     {  cout << "Crashed after " << i << " second" << endl;
     }
     else
     {  cout << "Crashed after " << i << " seconds" << endl;
     printRace(grid);
     i = 500;
  }
```

The `else` block has not been closed.

Comment: Oh wow I don't know how I missed that. Ok thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing curly bracket } in the else clause below:

```
  if((xAcceleration != 0) && (xAcceleration != 1) && (xAcceleration != -1))
  {  if(i == 1)
     {  cout << "Crashed after " << i << " second" << endl;
     }
     else
     {  cout << "Crashed after " << i << " seconds" << endl;
     printRace(grid);
     i = 500;
  }
```

Should be:

```
  if((xAcceleration != 0) && (xAcceleration != 1) && (xAcceleration != -1))
  {  if(i == 1)
     {  cout << "Crashed after " << i << " second" << endl;
     }
     else
     {  cout << "Crashed after " << i << " seconds" << endl;
        printRace(grid);
        i = 500;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a closing brace in the section below(at marked line):

```
  if((xAcceleration != 0) && (xAcceleration != 1) && (xAcceleration != -1))
  {  if(i == 1)
     { 
         cout << "Crashed after " << i << " second" << endl;
     }
     else
     {  
          cout << "Crashed after " << i << " seconds" << endl;
          printRace(grid);
          i = 500;
      }//<-- This was missing
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this block is missing a proper ending bracket,

```
if((xAcceleration != 0) && (xAcceleration != 1) && (xAcceleration != -1))
  {  if(i == 1)
     {  cout << "Crashed after " << i << " second" << endl;
     }
     else
     {  cout << "Crashed after " << i << " seconds" << endl;
     printRace(grid);
     i = 500;
  }
```